# How to do non-async execution?

Tags: javascript

I want to execute two lines of JS after each other, in order, line by line. How would this be achieved? In the case I need to implement this, arrow functions are not viable.

```
functionThatTakesSomeTime();
console.log("execute this after the function");
```

is there even a way to do this, and in that case how?

Comment: What's wrong with the pseudo-code you have?

Comment: Is the first function synchronic?

Comment: could you provide the context? Where do you need to call the function and log? And some explanations about function.

Comment: @BlindKai In my front-end, I am doing a request to my API and then do a redirect. However, the redirect is executed first which doesn't work since the request to API is supposed to send a cookie which will allow the redirect to work.

Comment: Then either `await` the async function (which you have to do inside an async function) or use the Promise API.

Comment: @MoltasDev could you please check, what's the nature of function? If the function is asynchronous you could try to wrap it in `Promise` or use `async`/`await` if it already is.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function someFunc() {
    await functionThatTakesSomeTime();
    console.log("execute this after the function");
}

someFunc();
```

If you are referring to an asynchronous function (functionThatTakesSomeTime), you can use async/await